# Is there a way to identify if the registrations on sip server are made from same application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sip, telecommunication, jssip

I am using Sip.js library to create a calling app. There seems to be times when the application registers itself multiple times, I have used ua.stop() method which serves the purpose of stopping the useragent but is there a way in which I can identify if all the registrations are made from same application or not so that I can handle them.

```
user_agent.stop().then(()=>console.log("ua stopped"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the extension defined in [rfc5626](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5626).

In this specification, you need to check the ***+sip.instance*** the ***reg-id*** parameters.

When **the same** application registers, you need to re-use the exact same ***+sip.instance*** the ***reg-id*** parameter. This is how the server can detect if the registration replaces an old one (*matching parameters*) or is a new one (*not matching parameters*).

> ```
> Contact: <sip:bob@192.0.2.2;transport=tcp>;reg-id=1
>  ;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-1000-8000-AABBCCDDEEFF>"
> ```

Of course, the server must support/understand those parameters.